# Windows Server 2008 DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, iis-7, internal-dns

We have Setup

vpn.mysite.com and mysite.com to point to the same ip address which is one of our servers.

We are trying to setup IIS to have it redirect requests to vpn.mysite.com to one interal ip and just mysite.com to another internal ip.

The server that is handling this is the VPN server.

How would we go about setting this up in the DNS manager?

Answer (score 0):

You do not. IIS can not redirect requests to an internal IP. This is not what IIS does. For that you need a program that does that, to start with.

Comment: Is that not what the `Windows Server 2008 DNS Manager` is for?

Comment: DNS Manager managed the DNS. What you ask for seems to be a reverse proxy.

Comment: Any hints or tutorials you know of?

Comment: I have found this tutorial http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/ which uses the urls `mysite.com/webmail` and `mysite.com/payroll` What would I need to change to get it to handle eg webmail.mysite.com and payroll.mysite.com

Answer (score 0):

As TomTom says in the comments - this requires a reverse proxy. So on the Microsoft side, any of:

- Application Request Routing for IIS 7
- Threat Management Gateway 2010
- ISA Server 2006
- UAG 2010

Could do the job.